# When I knit in R Markdown, LaTeX fails to compile and I get the error: ! Undefined control sequence

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, markdown, knitr

I am writing my thesis in R markdown and I get the following error when I try to knit:

> ! Undefined control sequence.
> l.404 ... We reject the null hypothesis of (r \eq 0) at a 1% level of
> Error: LaTeX failed to compile Thesis_Draft.tex.

The R markdown file includes tables, graphs, code chunks and math equations. What could be causing the problem with knitting?

Answer (score 2):

The issue I was having came from incorrectly typing `$r \eq 0$` instead of `$r \geq 0$`. Once I fixed this, I had no more issues knitting. If you get a similar error (! Undefined control sequence), check that any inline mathematical notation in the text chunks is valid.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community What information is missing? The incorrect macro was identified and the correct name is given.